# Linux GPIO | What is using some of my GPIO's?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gpio

I working with a device that has an i.MX280 and currently struggling with GPIO's.
I have tried to find GPIO's for the physical interfaces of the embedded machine i'm working with, but i am struggling with it.

Created my own .sh to export and sweep all GPIO and to echo if any GPIO changed at some point. Still haven't found a GPIO that i can physically connect to on-board.

Then i used "cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio" in order to locate two pins of a RS485 connection. I located them at gpio-99 ("DE") and gpio-102 ("RE").

How do i enable them in some way so i can control them with sysfs and be succesfully able to export them?

Comment: Did you refer the schematics of the device with iMX280 on it? Which GPIO's are externally accessible? Which kernel version you use? Assuming a recent device tree enabled kernel, are the accessible pins muxed as GPIO or to some alternate function?

Comment: **Schematics:** Unfortunately i don't have any access to schematics of the expansion cards that are attached to the main board. Since the expansion cards are the ones with externally available interfaces i have no clue what GPIO the are paired with. That is why i created my sweeping GPIO .sh and set active high on each port, but unfortunately with no result.

**Kernel version:** Linux cgate 2.6.35.3

**Pins muxed as GPIO or alternate function?:**
Do you mean if the GPIO's that are scanable are in sysfs or attached to another module or something? Most of the GPIO's are in sysfs.

Comment: If i run a "cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio" after trying to export all GPIO's to sysfs, most of them are available in sysfs, but there are still others that are "owned" by "DE" or "RE" as example. I have a feeling about those being a part of the RS485 interface.

Comment: Forgot to mention you @Sanchayan

Comment: If the concerned pin is in used by another driver which it seems to be for DE and RE, you cannot use them as GPIO unless you disable the use of those pins by the UART/RS 485 driver and mux the said pins as GPIO. 2.6.35 is just way too old and useless. Using a recent kernel would be recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Sanchayan.

How can i measure a digital or analog input on the RS 485?

In what way will a recent kernel be helpfull? :-)

Comment: First and good recommendation is to stop using ancient kernels.